# Position text on a responsive image relative to a specific part of the image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an image that I need to add text over (accessibility reasons). The image is responsive using bootstraps img-responsive class. The text needs to stay at the right part of the image even as the size of the image changes. Is there a way to do this with CSS?

Here is a basic example:

```
<style>
span#mad {
    position: relative;
    top: 440px;
    left: 440px;
}
</style>
<span id="mad">
    Madagascar
</span>
<div id="map">
    <img src="http://www.freeworldmaps.net/printable/africa/countries.png" 
    class="img-responsive"/>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/95125/

The label of Madagascar should always remain above the island.

Comment: This might be significantly easier by just adding the text to the image using a software like paint instead of positioning it using html.

Comment: Like I said, the text can't be part of the image for accessibility reasons (WCAG 1.4.5).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you're looking for static text or dynamic text but it sounds like [PopperJS](https://popper.js.org/) is what you're looking for.  If your img isn't filling up the whole div and this creates an unwanted gap, give your img an id so you can reference it directly instead of the wrapping div.

```
var popper = new Popper(document.getElementById("mad"), document.getElementById("map"), {
    placement: 'bottom'
});
```

Comment: I am familiar with this as a tooltip solution. I haven't seen it used on images or as a permanent marker (as in always showing, rather than having to click or hover to display it)

Comment: I thought of this because you wanted something that stayed in position while the image is responsive to the frame. While this is indeed commonly used as a tooltip, it has the option of staying on the screen permanently (without hover or click) and you can adjust the display with css to be flush with your template so it doesn't stick out like a tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the child-parent relationship, with position relative on the parent and absolute on the child you want to position.

Since an `<img>` can't have children. we can mimic it by using a `div` element and add both the text and the `img` inside, This way we can have the child-parent relationship.

## DEMO

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

div>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
  <span>some text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I put your code into my example at: 
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/95130/ 

It doesn't seem to work. Madagascar is only in the right spot at certain page widths.

Comment: `The text needs to stay at the right part of the image` 
replace `left: 280px;` with `right:0;` and instead of `top:280px` use 50% [Check](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/95131/)